# why is update_user_meta creating arrays when trying to change the same value?

Tags: plugin-development

I added a custom field using update_user_meta to count the products user can buy. Initially the counter starts at 10 and after buying each product the field is deducted by the number of products user bought. 
Here is the code

```
function deduct_product($order_id){
  $order=wc_get_order($order_id);
  $items=$order->get_items();
  $quantity=0;
  foreach($items as $item_id => $item_data){
    $quantity+=$item_data->get_quantity();
  }
  $remaining_products=get_user_meta(get_current_user_id(),'remaining_products');  
  $remaining_products-=$quantity;
  update_user_meta(get_current_user_id(  ),'remaining_products',$remaining_products);
}
```

It gives me error that unsupported operand types on line where i have used $remaining_products-=$quantity. How do I change the user meta for remaining_products by the number of products user has bought.

Comment: read https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_user_meta/ - you might need to set the '$single' parameter to 'true'...

Comment: Yayyy Your tip worked and it is running smoothly now. I kept checking the update_user_meta function and never thought about that.